# How would I make this counter work?

Tags: java, counter, do-while

My counter is in a separate method from the main. I am trying to accumulate the number of wins, losses, and ties in multiple Rock-Paper-Scissors games. The counter only adds to the value once; as soon as I play the game again, the counter is reset and does not include results from the previous game...

```
    do{
System.out.println("\n1=Rock\n2=Paper\n3=Scissors\n===========\nChoose:");

choice = Integer.parseInt(myInput.readLine());

determineOutcome();
System.out.println("\nYou have chosen " + ans);
System.out.println("The computer has chosen " + cans);
System.out.println("\nYOU'VE" + result);
System.out.println("\nWINS: " + win);
System.out.println("LOSSES: " + loss);
System.out.println("TIES: " + tie);

System.out.println("\nPress 1 to play again.");
loop = myInput.readLine();
}while("1".equals(loop));
} // end main method



public static void determineOutcome(){

// Randomize computer's choice (# between 1 and 3)
cchoice = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;

// User's choice
switch ((int)choice)
{
    case 1: ans = (" Rock.");
        break;
    case 2: ans = (" Paper.");
        break;
    case 3: ans = (" Scissors.");
        break;
}
// Assign computer's number choice to a string
switch ((int)cchoice)
{
    case 1: cans = (" Rock.");
        break;
    case 2: cans = (" Paper.");
        break;
    case 3: cans = (" Scissors.");
        break;
}

win = 0;
loss = 0;
tie = 0;

if (choice == 1 && cchoice==3 || choice == 2 && cchoice == 1 || choice == 3 && cchoice == 2){
    result = (" WON");
    win++;
}

else if (choice == cchoice){
    result = (" TIED");
    tie++;
}
else if (choice == 1 && cchoice==2 || choice == 2 && cchoice == 3 || choice == 3 && cchoice == 1){
    result = (" LOST");
    loss++;
}
} // end determineOutcome(); method
```

Do I need to add a loop in the determineOutcome(); method? If so, where? I tried putting it around the entire thing and it did not work.

Comment: First of all, learn how to format the code; it is very difficult to read it!

Comment: Please share the information , does the main thread terminate after each game and does this game run as a part of the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this every time you call the method:

```
win = 0;
loss = 0;
tie = 0;
```

I assume you have initialized the variables before calling the method, so dont set them to 0 every time you call the method. Remove this piece of code and it might just work :)